# probability of second highest no in a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $n$ real no are drawn at random from the uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$. For $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$, what is the probability that the second highest number drawn is $<= x$?

Answer (score 1):

We may use the PDF formula for [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)

$$
f_{X_{(k)}}(x) =\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}[F_X(x)]^{k-1}[1-F_X(x)]^{n-k} f_X(x)
$$

For a uniform distribution, we write it as

$$f_{X_{(k)}}(x) =\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\, x^{k-1}\,(1-x)^{n-k}$$

For your question,

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{(n-1)}\le a)=\int_0^a\, \frac{n!}{(n-2)!(1)!}\, x^{n-2}\,(1-x)^{1}\, dx$$

E.g., if we choose 10 numbers in $U(0,1)$, the probability that the second highest number is less than 0.9 is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{(9)}\le 9/10)&=\int_0^{9/10}\, \frac{10!}{(8)!(1)!}\, x^{8}\,(1-x)^{1}\, dx\\
&=\frac{7360989291}{10000000000}
\end{align}